# Rushing Yards Gained on an Offensive Fumble Recovery

Tags: american-football

I am trying to understand how many yards a running back gained on a play in which he fumbled. Here is the situation: Derrick Henry rushes the ball for 5-yards but fumbles the ball which is recovered by another offensive player 2-yards behind his initial 5-yard gain. Is Derrick Henry credited with 5-yards rushing or 3-yards rushing?